# Posicionar elementos alineados en header

Tags: html, css, responsive

Estoy aprendiendo a programar por mi cuenta, para ello, estoy poniendo en práctica lo aprendido hasta ahora con mi primera web, un blog personal.

Ahora estoy aplicando los estilos de pantalla principal, estoy liado con el header.

Estoy intentando posicionar los elementos de tal forma que queden alineados de manera adecuada, y no hay manera. Como una imagen dice más que mil palabras, os voy a poner los pantallazos, y además, el código, para así explicarme mejor.

[image: Header]

Os pego el HTML del header. (Por alguna razón no me deja el CSS).

```
<header>
    <img src="./img/carga-en-la-nube.png" alt="Logotipo del blog">
    <h1>La web de Abdón Víñez: Tu web de tecnología, programación y videojuegos.</h1>
    <nav class="inicio">
        <a href="./first.html">Inicio</a>
    </nav>
    <nav class="twitch">
        <a href="">Twitch</a>
    </nav>
    <nav class="contacto">
        <a href="">Contacto</a>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Lo que estoy intentando es que el h1 se suba arriba y no se solape con las barras de navegación, después, estoy buscando que el título se centre en el centro de la imagen, para después, poner las barras de navegación un poco por debajo y separadas entre sí.

He intentado poner el h1 con la opción `position: top;`, sin éxito, me dice que la opción no es válida. Por otro lado, la imagen la tengo en static porque no quiero que le afecten los cambios del título o de los nav.

¿Qué opciones debo utilizar? ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: No entiendo muy bien que quieres conseguir, podrías poner una imagen aunque sea hecha en paint representativa de lo que quieres conseguir ?

Comment: Buenas Rodri :D Estoy intentando hacer que el titulo parta desde el centro de la imagen. El navar, que quede debajo de la imagen con sus respectivos espaciados. Creo que el problema se haya en que he puesto todo el header en display inline, y a lo mejor, la imgen deba de quedarse en block.

Comment: "Por alguna razón no me deja el CSS": como tu pregunta es acerca de html/css, puedes adjuntar tu código como snippet (con el botón que indica `<>`) para crear un [repro] en tu propia pregunta.